# Load Dynamic Select - PHP VS AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a pretty lengthy form with about 10 select fields that all load data from other tables (mysql).  My question is should I load the data using php/mysql as the page loads or should I let the page load first and then grab the select options for each field using ajax?  If I load the select fields using php/mysql I would have 10 trips to the server before the page completely loaded (if my thinking is correct).

My initial thought is to first load the page and then load the select fields using ajax.  Would this give me a faster load time or should I just load all the select fields using php/mysql on page load?

Any thoughts, theories or strategies would be helpful.  I want my pages to load as fast as possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say do it on the server-side (in php) because if you do it in ajax you're doing a client side request to the server to do the same thing. If i'm not mistaken from what you're saying ------- its 10 separate selects done in php that happens before the page loads... as opposed to an ajax request to do 10 separate selects as the page loads in javascript (meaning its a second request to do the same thing).. server side would be the best option in this case

Comment: Yeah they both make trips to the server but because the ajax doesn't have to wait for the browser to load, would letting the selects load in the background make the page load faster?  I don't want the page to have heavy load time waiting to run 10 queries before the browser is fully loaded.

Comment: the browser loading wouldn't affect the php running queries either. as the page loads, the queries are run because thats part of whats building the page. unless your system is set up differently

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it would be faster to do it on the server-side before any headers are sent to the browser.  Then your data is send along with the rest of the page to load.  One trip.  With AJAX you're sending the page first, then the javascript you just sent has to do a separate request for the data.  Two trips instead of one.  AJAX is best used when you can avoid requesting new http headers, but if you're doing that anyway, I'd skip it.